# Create a dataframe where the number and the name of the columns are determined at runtime

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to create a data frame whose columns are the consecutive elements of multiple vectors, all vectors having the same length. For example, with vectors `p` and `q`

```
p=c(13,27,35,47)
q=c(800,700,600,400)
```

I would like to build a data frame

```
df=data.frame(q1=q[1],q2=q[2],q3=q[3],q4=q[4],p1=p[1],p2=p[2],p3=p[3],p4=p[4])
```

The difficulty is that the length of the vectors is determined at runtime, thus it could be `4`, as in the example, or `5`, `6`, etc. I want the number and the name of the columns to be automatically updated at runtime, without having to rewrite the `data.frame` assignment statement each time. Is that doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can place it in a `list` and convert to `data.frame`

```
d1 <- data.frame(as.list(c(q,p)))
names(d1) <- c(paste0('q', seq_along(q)), paste0('p', seq_along(p)))
```

or use `as.data.frame.list`

```
d2 <- cbind(as.data.frame.list(q), as.data.frame.list(p))
```

We can also use `make.unique` to name the columns

```
make.unique(rep(c('q', 'p'),lengths(list(q,p))))
```

Comment: don't worry, the comment doesn't apply to your edited code. Thanks!